# Pandas DataFrame: Why I can't change the value of one column based on value of another through row iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I want to change the value of one column based on that value of another. For example, given the following DF:

```
   Freq TOC
1    10  NA
2    20  NA
3    30  NA

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["Freq"] == 20:
        row["TOC"] = True
```

I would expect:

```
   Freq TOC
1    10  NA
2    20  True
3    30  NA
```

But nothing is changed. What's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`pd.DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) returns a series for each row in a Python-level loop, not dynamic links to your dataframe. More efficiently, you can use column-wise vectorised methods instead of a row-wise loop (this assumes you are happy with `1 == True`):

```
df['TOC'] = np.where(df['Freq'] == 20, True, np.nan)
```

More idiomatic is to assign a **Boolean series**, i.e. `True` / `False` values only:

```
df['TOC'] = df['Freq'] == 20
```

What would work is utilising the index in your loop, although this will be inefficient:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Freq'] == 20:
        df.loc[index, 'TOC'] = True
```

Comment: `df['TOC'] = df['Freq'] == 20` resets the remaining rows to `False`, which does not seem to be the OP's intent.

Comment: @CJ59, Yes, I've clearly mentioned that it's *more idiomatic* to have a Boolean series output [than create an inefficient `object` dtype series]. My first option does what OP wants.

Comment: `np.where` will coerce the `True` values to `1.0`, so your first method does not exactly give what OP expected.

Comment: @coldspeed, Sure, added a disclaimer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a followup question. I now understand that it's not efficient to change values through row iteration. I have a task where I need to compare  the value of a column with the rows before and after. If it is out of order, I will add a flag to the Out-of-Seq column. What's the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Look up [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html), you can use something like `df['Out-of-Seq'] = df['TOC'] != df['TOC'].shift()`. Try it and check the result.

Answer (score 6):

You modify a "copy" of a row, not the row itself.

In general, one should not use loops to modify dataframes. Instead, resort to the vectorized operations:

```
df.loc[df["Freq"]==20, "TOC"] = True
```

Comment: It's a technical, but important, point to note that a "copy of a row" has little meaning for a dataframe. Data is organised in columns. Taking a row of numeric & text types, for example, gives an `object` dtype series. This is an inefficient conversion, not an efficient copy.

Comment: @jpp Agree. I'll quote the "copy" word.

Comment: this solution is more general, which means this solution can meet most of situations